# Conditional formatting in excel based on previous left cell

Tags: excel

I have table like this. [image]

I want to conditionally format columns worked hours where worked hours are 1,5 less then existing Capacity In Hours, and to get table like this 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Excel you are using you can simply click on *Conditional Formatting* -> *New Rule* -> *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* then simply add the relevant formula (referencing the cell on the left) in the **Format values where this formula is true** box

Comment: Actually I am asking for that formula

Comment: I am looking at the same problem. It seems that excel does not resolve expressions dynamically when doing conditional evaluation. For example, `=INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN()-1;FALSE)` doesn´t work