# How to deal with double quotes in conditional formatting's formula

Tags: excel, debugging, conditional-formatting, double-quotes, decimal-point

I was having a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316812/conditional-formatting-in-excel-based-on-previous-left-cell), and in order to help, I wrote a conditional formatting rule, based on this formula:

```
="ABS(B3-A3)>=1,5" // the double-quotes are automatically added by Excel
```

This, however, seems not to work, although the formula seems to be correct (in the cell at the right, I asked whether this was true and I got a positive result, as you can see (`WAAR` is Dutch for true)):

[image: Excel screenshot]

I'm not interested in the final solution, I just want to know how I can debug such a situation: apparantly the formula is true, but still the conditional formatting is not applied. This might mean that:

- Something is wrong with the language settings.
- **Something is wrong with the dot/comma decimal separator.**
- Something else is wrong with the formula (absolute references, relative references, ...)

How can I, step by step, evaluate the formula, entered in a conditional formatting configuration, in order to see what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For what range is the formula applied?

Comment: First I did it for the four cells in B column, but as this did not work, I tried it solely for cell B3 (which still did not work out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, guys, but the truth is really nerve-wrecking:

- The answer of Error 1004 is correct. Thanks for the screenshot.
- The answer of Jario is correct too.

So what's the deal?

Apparently there seems to be a problem with the decimal separator : when I enter a dot, using Excel regularly, it gets converted into a comma. When I enter a dot in a conditional formatting formula, this conversion is not done, resulting in a wrong formula, where Excel automatically adds double quotes. As the double quotes result in a wrong formula, the conditional formatting won't be applied.

So:
**From the moment you see double quotes in a conditional formula, this is an indication that something's wrong, and that your conditional formatting won't work!**

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the whole range (for the example A2:B5)
2. Add in conditional formatting formula `=ABS($B3-$A3)>=1.5`

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "" at the beginning and end of your formula. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, if you don't include the equal sign as the first character of the line, Excel will insert double quotes around your entire entry.  Using the original example, if you enter

ABS(B3-A3)>=1,5   you will get   ="ABS(B3-A3)>=1,5"

However, if you enter

=ABS(B3-A3)>=1,5  you will get    =ABS(B3-A3)>=1,5